# python 3 regex pattern replacement

Tags: python, regex, csv, newline

I have a malformed csv file which I need to fix:

- The file is supposed to have one record per line but because of this formatting issue, it has a MS-DOS newline character (`^M`).
- To make matters worse, the last field of the CSV file is a text field and it also contains this MS-DOS newline character so I can't simply replace `^M` character.
- But the good news is that the first field of the file is DATE field (`MM/DD/YY`)

So I tried to replace (`\r\nMM/DD/YY`) pattern by (`\rMM/DD/YY`) but it didn't work. Here is my code snippet:

```
fixed_content = re.sub(r"""\r\n\d{2})/\d{2}/\d{2}""", r"""\r\1/\2/\3""", malformed_content)
```

My problems are:

1. I don't know how to represent `^M` character as a pattern. I used `\r\n`
2. I don't know how to refer to previous matches in the new replacing pattern. I used `\1` for first `MM` pattern, `\2` for next `DD` pattern and `\3` for last `YY` pattern.

Comment: Previous matches must be grouped in brackets `(...)` for backtracking.

Comment: Thanks. Let me retry and see tomorrow!

Comment: For 1. that seems to be the correct way to represent the MS-DOS newline character. 2. Your replacement shouldn't have worked because your regex is malformed (contains unbalanced parentheses). You will have to *capture* every match you want to get back, so something like: `r"""\r\n(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})"""` but it's so much easier to just do `re.sub(r"""\r\n(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2})""", r"""\r\1""", malformed_content)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a date string in the form `DD/MM/YY` you can use the following regexp:

```python
 \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}
```

If you then want to [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) the matched string you have to put it between brackets `(...)` like so:

```python
 (\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})
```

The overall substitution command would then become:

```python
fixed_content = re.sub(r"""\r\n(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})""", r"""\r\1""", malformed_content)
```

Please note that I escaped the backslash `\/` as this is sometimes required (in cases in which the backslash is used as a delimiter between match/replace strings). Modify to fit your needs.